# Ionic 3 post data to Codeigniter Rest API

Tags: angular, codeigniter, http-post, ionic3

I am trying to post signup form data from my ionic app. I use ionic 3 and Codeigniter Rest Api as the backend.

Codeigniter Rest Api : 
[Codeigniter Rest Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

This is my **ionic post** function

```
postAuthData(data:any){
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8');
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    this.http.post("http://localhost/giftinrest/index.php/api/example/users", data,{headers:headers})
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res.json());
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  })
}
```

This is my **codeigniter post** function

```
public function users_post()
{

    $message = [
        'id' => 100, // Automatically generated by the model
        'name' => $this->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->post('email'),
        'message' => 'Added a resource'
    ];

    $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // CREATED (201) being the HTTP response code
}
```

And i get null for $this->post('email').

I tried changing headers but it did not work.

I tried with postman post requests to http://localhost/giftinrest/index.php/api/example/users and it works.

Is there any solution/recommendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a proper solution but it works like this. I place following code inside **codeigniter post** method to get post values.

```
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($post_data);
$name = $request->name;
```

instead of $this->post().

It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In CI to get post data you can do this:

```
$this->input->post();
```

Comment: cannot get like this t works like below

$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($post_data);